# Ipc using message queues gets caller key error

Tags: c, message-queue

I tried to run the message queue program of a telephonic conversation between a caller and a receiver given here with the correction stated. I keep getting the following result:

```
 ./caller
 Caller Program

 Caller send key error
 Caller send key error
 Receiver send key error
```

while running the caller executable.

The caller.c is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct msgbuf
{
long mtype;
char mtext[140];
}msg_buf;

int send_msg_id,receive_msg_id;
key_t send_key,receive_key;

void *send_message(void *a)
{
send_key=ftok("Caller1.c",'A');
if (send_key==-1)
{
    printf("\nCaller send key error");
    exit(1);
}
send_msg_id=msgget(send_key,0666 | IPC_CREAT);
if (send_msg_id==-1)
{   
    printf("\nCaller send msgget error");
    exit(1);
}
printf("\nCALLER:");
while (fgets(msg_buf.mtext,sizeof(msg_buf.mtext),stdin)!=NULL)
{
    msg_buf.mtype=1;
    int len=strlen(msg_buf.mtext);
    if (msg_buf.mtext[len-1]=='\n');
        msg_buf.mtext[len-1]='\0';
    if (msgsnd(send_msg_id,&msg_buf,len+1,0)==-1)
        printf("\nMsg sending error\n");
}
int i=0;
while(i<9999)
    i++;
msgctl(send_msg_id,IPC_RMID,NULL);
return;
}

void *receive_message(void *a)
{
receive_key=ftok("Receiver1.c",'B');
if (receive_key==-1)
{
    printf("\nReceiver send key error");
    exit(1);
}
send_msg_id=msgget(receive_key,0777|IPC_CREAT);
if (receive_msg_id==-1)
{
    printf("\nCaller msgrcv error");
    exit(1);
}
printf("\n<<<");
while(1)
{
    if(msgrcv(receive_msg_id,&msg_buf,sizeof(msg_buf.mtext),1,0)!=-1)
        printf("<<<%s\n",msg_buf.mtext);
}
return;
 }

 void initialize()
 {
    pthread_t send_thread,receive_thread;
    pthread_create(&send_thread,NULL,send_message,NULL);
    pthread_create(&receive_thread,NULL,receive_message,NULL);
    pthread_join(send_thread,NULL);
    pthread_join(receive_thread,NULL);
    return;
 }

 int main() 
 {
    printf("\nCaller Program\n");
    initialize();
    return 0;
 }
```

The receiver program is the same error. The reciever.c is almost the same as the the caller.c:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <errno.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/ipc.h>
 #include <sys/msg.h>
 #include <pthread.h>

 struct msgbuf
 {
long mtype;
char mtext[140];
 }msg_buf;

 int send_msg_id,receive_msg_id;
 key_t send_key,receive_key;

 void *send_message(void *a)
 {
send_key=ftok("Receiver1.c",'A');
if (send_key==-1)
{
    printf("\nReceiver send key error");
    exit(1);
}
send_msg_id=msgget(send_key,0777 | IPC_CREAT);
if (send_msg_id==-1)
{   
    printf("\nReceiver send msgget error");
    exit(1);
}
printf("\nRECEIVER:");
while (fgets(msg_buf.mtext,sizeof(msg_buf.mtext),stdin)!=NULL)
{
    msg_buf.mtype=1;
    int len=strlen(msg_buf.mtext);
    if (msg_buf.mtext[len-1]=='\n')
        msg_buf.mtext[len-1]='\0';
    if (msgsnd(send_msg_id,&msg_buf,len+1,0)==-1)
        printf("\nMessage sending error");
}
int i=0;
while(i<9999)
    i++;
msgctl(send_msg_id,IPC_RMID,NULL);
return;
 }

 void *receive_message(void *a)
 {
receive_key=ftok("Caller1.c",'B');
if (receive_key==-1)
{
    printf("\nReceiver send key error");
    exit(1);
}
send_msg_id=msgget(receive_key,0666|IPC_CREAT);
if (receive_msg_id==-1)
{
    printf("\nCaller msgrcv error");
    exit(1);
}
printf("\n<<<");
while(1)
{
    if(msgrcv(receive_msg_id,&msg_buf,sizeof(msg_buf.mtext),1,0)!=-1)
        printf("<<<%s\n",msg_buf.mtext);
}
return;
}

void initialize()
{
    pthread_t send_thread,receive_thread;
    pthread_create(&send_thread,NULL,send_message,NULL);
    pthread_create(&receive_thread,NULL,receive_message,NULL);
    pthread_join(send_thread,NULL);
    pthread_join(receive_thread,NULL);
    return;
}

int main()
{
    printf("\nReceiver Program\n");
    initialize();
    return 0;
}
```

The receiver gives the same error as the caller:

```
Receiver Program

Receiver send key error
Receiver send key error
```

Comment: Instead of `printf("\nCaller send key error");` use `perror("Caller send key error (ftok)");` and you might get enlighted. Same for other error-messages indicating failed system-calls.

Comment: Receiver send key error(ftok): No such file or directory
Caller send key error(ftok): No such file or directory

This is the error that i get now..

Comment: So now turn to the documentation of the system calls in question an look up the error.

Comment: Yes sorry the error is my file name ..ir should be low r in place of R

Comment: But i get two different terminals and yes they take input..but the sender sent message is not sent on the other terminal however

Comment: This seems to be a different issue, so you might like to pose another question for it.